# Macbook White (2010) screen driver problem

Tags: drivers, nvidia, lubuntu, mac

I have Macbook White (A1342, mid2010 (7.1), NVidia GeForce 320M (256 mb.)). It was necessary to install ubuntu on it. I have installed Lubuntu to make computer faster.
Otherwise, after installing I noticed screen is not such colorful and contrast as in Mac OS therefore eyes are tired very fast. It is not comfortable to use.
Are there any solutions to solve the problem?
Is it worth install any different iso from Ubuntu family with necassary screen driver included maybe?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Possible: https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available

Comment: @Terrance Matter is not at shell

Comment: Those are not shells!  Those are Desktop Environments that you can choose from.  Xfce (Xubuntu) is lighter weight that might be easier on your eyes.  I just put that there to help you make your decision since really we can't make that for you.